# gradle 8 declare configuratioin as dependency issue [ worked in gradle 7.5]

Tags: gradle

I have recently migrated from gradle 7.5 to gradle 8, i have configuration as dependency but after changing required syntax for gradle 8.0 for configuration, seeing imports not working in java file.

```
config.gradle:
============
`configurations {
    jsoup.extendsFrom(implementation)
}

dependencies {
    jsoup  group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.16.1'
}

build.gradle:
============

apply from: 'config.gradle'
dependencies {
    
configurations.jsoup   ===> ?? i'm not able to figure it out here, gradle issue resolved but now getting     jsoups imports compilatioin issues, how to declare this dependency here?
}
```

Comment: this was perfectly answered here, genuis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830234/extend-from-configuration-from-another-gradle-project